# Values from nested array in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift 3.

I am getting the following response from a server and i need to parse and get values such as, Account No, Account Type, Address etc.

```
parsedData: (
        {
        key = "<null>";
        offset = 1;
        partition = 0;
        topic = test;
        value =         {
            "Account No" = 675;
            "Account Type" = Saving;
            Address = location;
            User ID = 601;
            User Name = Stella;
        };
    }
)
```

I have been trying to get value first, and then planning to get each value,

```
var temp: NSArray = parsedData["value"] as! NSArray
```

but this is giving error as `cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type Int.'`

How to retrieve values from the above mentioned array?

Comment: try `var temp = parsedData["value"] as? NSDictionary`

Comment: Do not use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift. You are fighting the strong type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parsedData` is an `array` which contains `Dictionary` at first index.

```
let dicData = parsedData[0] as! Dictionary

let valueDictionary = dicData["value"] as! Dictionary  //dicData  also contains dictionary for key `value`


let accountNumber = valueDictionary ["Account No"] //**Account number**
```

//////SECOND APPROACH IF YOU HAVE DICTIONARY IN RESPONSE

```
var valueDictionary : NSDictionary = parsedData["value"] as? NSDictionary 
    let accountNumber = valueDictionary ["Account No"] //**Account number**
```

Comment: It gives error as "cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type Int.' and error points "value"

Comment: This one worked. let dicData = parsedData[0] as! NSDictionary
                let valueDictionary = dicData["value"] as! NSDictionary
                
                let accountNumber = valueDictionary.object(forKey: "Account No")
                let accountType = valueDictionary.object(forKey: "Account Type")
                let address = valueDictionary.object(forKey: "Address")
                let userID = valueDictionary.object(forKey: "User ID")
                let userName = valueDictionary.object(forKey: "User Name")

Answer (score 0):

You parse a dictionary as an array

```
var temp: NSDictionary = parsedData["value"] as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: It gives error as "cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type Int.' and error points "value"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let dicData = parsedData[0] as! Dictionary
var temp: NSDictionary = dicData["value"] as? NSDictionary
let accountNumber = temp.object(forKey: "Account No")
let accountType = temp.object(forKey: "Account Type")
let address = temp.object(forKey: "Address")
let userID = temp.object(forKey: "User ID")
let userName = temp.object(forKey: "User Name")
```

Comment: It gives error as "cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type Int.' and error points "value"